# python requests login with redirect

Tags: authentication, redirect, web-scraping, python-requests

I'd like to automate my log in to my bank to automatically fetch my transactions to stay up-to-date with spendings and earnings, but I am stuck.

The bank's login webpage is: https://login.bancochile.cl/bancochile-web/persona/login/index.html#/login

I am using python's request module with sessions:

```
urlLoginPage = 'https://login.bancochile.cl/bancochile-web/persona/login/index.html'
urlLoginSubmit = 'https://login.bancochile.cl/oam/server/auth_cred_submit'

username = '11.111.111-1'  # this the format of a Chilean National ID ("RUT")
usernameFormatted = '111111111'  # same id but formatted
pw = "password"

payload = [
    ("username2", usernameFormatted),
    ("username2", username),
    ("userpassword", pw),
    ("request_id", ''),
    ("ctx", "persona"),
    ("username", usernameFormatted),
    ("password", pw),
]

with requests.Session() as session:
    login = session.get(urlLoginPage)
    postLogin = session.post(
        urlLoginSubmit,
        data=payload,
        allow_redirects=False,
    )
    redirectUrl = postLogin.headers["Location"]
```

First I find that the form data has duplicated keys, so I am using the payload as a list of tuples. From Chrome's inspect I find the form data to be like this:

```
username2=111111111&username2=11.111.111-1&userpassword=password&request_id=&ctx=persona&username=111111111&password=password
```

I've checked the page's source code to look for the use of a csrf token, but couldn't find any hint of it.

What happens is that the site does a redirect upon submitting the login data. I set `allow_redirects=False` to catch the redirect url of the post under the Location-header. However, here is the problem. Using the web-browser I know that the redirect url should be `https://portalpersonas.bancochile.cl/mibancochile/rest/persona/perfilamiento/home`, but I always end up on an error page when using the above method (`https://login.bancochile.cl/bancochile-web/contingencia/error404.html`). (I am using my own, correct login credentials to try this)

If I submit the payload in a wrong format (e.g. by dropping a key) I am redirected to the same error-page. This tells me that probably something with the payload is incorrect, but I don't know how to find out what may be wrong.

I am kind of stuck and don't know how I can figure out where/how to look for errors and possible solutions. Any suggestions on how to debug this and continue or ideas for other approaches would be very welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you've done a lot. Have you considered adding in the headers and cookies in the request to the bank ? Sounds like you've properly profiled the requests/response to the page. Also is it not that you want to allow redirects ? What happens when you set allow_redirects=True ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I've also tried with `allow_redirects=True`, but the log-in is unsuccessful. I figured to check that the first redirect is correct would be a good cross-check, but, as explained in the post, it fails there as I get the wrong url.
I'll do a element by element comparison of the headers to see if I am missing any or have some wrongly configured.